# race condition для HTTP запроса

Tags: golang, race-condition

Я хочу создать функцию, которая проверяет свободен ли ник в базе Mysql и если свободен, функция создает новую запись в БД. Пользователь одновременно отправляет несколько запросов на проверку свободного ника `user` и записывает этот ник.
В этот момент другие одновременные запросы пользователя тоже могут получить такой ответ, хотя по факту, юзер уже занял этот ник.

Как правильно обработать такой кейс, не блокируя запросы других пользователей к этой функции?

Использую в качестве фреймворка Fiber.

Comment: как я понял тут задача `кто успел того и тапки` в таком случае думаю самое надежное двухфакторная проверка, т.е. на все запросы идут уникальные ответы при получении обратно одного из этих ответов, приславший его считается победителем все остальные отпадают, можно как-то хэшировать IP и ник для отправки уникальных ответов

Answer (score 0):

Попробую описать по шагам, надеюсь реализовать при желании сможете самостоятельно:

1. Пользователи шлют запрос на создание какого-то ника например `ISuper`
2. Проверяете есть ли он в базе если есть и занят сразу отказываете
3. Если нет добавляете в базу но не отвечаете пользователю а выдаете ему некий ответ (токен) — таким образом ник пока зарезервирован
4. При следующем обращении пользователь отсылает полученный токен обратно на сервер
5. Сервер смотрит с каким ником ассоциируется этот токен (который уже в базе)
6. Если он еще не присвоен никому то присваивается именно этому пользователю
7. Следующие запросы будут автоматически отклонятся так как ник в базе уже ассоциирован с конкретным токеном пользователя.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал таблицу с никами: `ник`, `статус`, `дата истечения`, `идентификатор сессии`

Статусы - `активен` или `захвачен`. Для статуса `активен` остальные колонки пустые.

Для статуса `захвачен` идентификатор сессии указывает, какой именно из гостей попытался захватить идентификатор, дата истечения указывает, когда захват спадёт, если пользователь не зарегистрируется под этим ником

Проверка ников осуществляется по этой таблице:

1. Если ника в таблице нет, то ник свободен
2. Если ник в таблице, статус `захвачен`, и идентификатор сессии совпадает с идентификатором сессии гостя, то ник свободен

В противном случае ник считается занятым.

Если гость зарегается под указанным ником, то нику нужно присвоить состояние `активен` и удалить дату истечения и идентификтор сессии.

Если гость не зарегается до даты истечения, то строку с ником удалить.

Comment: А почему бы просто не сделать колонку username уникальной для таблицы?

Comment: само собой он уникален, но представьте такой кейс - пользователь ввёл имя, проверил на уникальность, затем изменил, снова проверил - новое имя оказалось неуникальным. Пользователь вернулся к предыдущему и ... если просто имя в таблице, то оно уже занято. Поэтому я бы хранил идентификатор сессии гостя, чтобы гость мог несколько раз проверить имя, и каждый раз раз получать ответ "свободно"